# ListView doesn't show any information from DB

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

well, I'm making a small application for accounting clients and materials, there is a database from which clients are taken. on the main page there is a ListView and a button for adding a new user to the database. the user is successfully added, but the data is not displayed in the ListView.

The client fragment page:

```
package com.example.uchet;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Client extends Fragment {
    protected DatabaseClient db;
    ArrayList<ClientModel> arrayList;
    ListView clients;
    ClientsListAdapter clientsListAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        db = new DatabaseClient(this.getContext(), null, null, 1);
        createListClients(inflater, container);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_client, container, false);
    }

    public void createListClients(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
        arrayList = db.getAllData();
        clients = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_client, container, false).findViewById(R.id.clientsList);
        clientsListAdapter = new ClientsListAdapter(this.getContext(), arrayList);
        clients.setAdapter(clientsListAdapter);
        clientsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The client model code:

```
package com.example.uchet;

public class ClientModel {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String patronymic;
    String phone;
    String email;

    public ClientModel(String firstname, String lastname, String patronymic, String phone, String email){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public ClientModel(){}

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getPatronymic() {
        return patronymic;
    }

    public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) {
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

The main activity code:

```
package com.example.uchet;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.uchet.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter;
import com.example.uchet.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    protected DatabaseClient db;
    ArrayList<ClientModel> arrayList;
    ListView clients;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        db = new DatabaseClient(this, null, null, 1);

        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = binding.viewPager;
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = binding.tabs;
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



        tabs.getTabAt(0).setText("Клиенты");
        tabs.getTabAt(1).setText("Материалы");

        tabs.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));

        tabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void onAddClientClick(View view) {
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(this, NewClientActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onBackClick(View view){
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

The client's database code:

```
package com.example.uchet;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseClient extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "uchet.db";
    public static final String CLIENT_TABLE = "clients";
    public static final String CLIENT_COLUMN_1 = "ID";
    public static final String CLIENT_COLUMN_2 = "FIRSTNAME";
    public static final String CLIENT_COLUMN_3 = "LASTNAME";
    public static final String CLIENT_COLUMN_4 = "PATRONYMIC";
    public static final String CLIENT_COLUMN_5 = "TELEPHONE";
    public static final String CLIENT_COLUMN_6 = "EMAIL";

    public DatabaseClient(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CLIENT_TABLE + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(50), LASTNAME VARCHAR(50), PATRONYMIC VARCHAR(50), TELEPHONE VARCHAR(50), EMAIL VARCHAR(50))");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CLIENT_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String FIRSTNAME, String LASTNAME, String PATRONYMIC, String TELEPHONE, String EMAIL){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(CLIENT_COLUMN_2, FIRSTNAME);
        values.put(CLIENT_COLUMN_3, LASTNAME);
        values.put(CLIENT_COLUMN_4, PATRONYMIC);
        values.put(CLIENT_COLUMN_5, TELEPHONE);
        values.put(CLIENT_COLUMN_6, EMAIL);

        long result = db.insert(CLIENT_TABLE, null, values);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ClientModel> getAllData(){
        ArrayList<ClientModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from clients", null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String lastname = cursor.getString(2);
            String patronymic = cursor.getString(3);
            String phone = cursor.getString(4);
            String email = cursor.getString(5);

            ClientModel client = new ClientModel(name, lastname, patronymic, phone, email);

            arrayList.add(client);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

The client fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Client">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/clientsList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onAddClientClick"
            android:text="Добавить" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The view for the data row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clientName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clientLastname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clientPatronymic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clientPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clientEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to change the layout, to check the database (works fine). But nothings helped. Data just not showing.